# CP1252 to UTF-8 .DBF file PHP

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, windows-1252, cp1252

I have a problem, I can not convert my string from CP1252 to UTF-8, my string comes from a .DBF (Windows) file that is read by my PHP functions

- *My application is fully encoded in UTF8*

My file .dbf is load with **[php-xbase](https://github.com/hisamu/php-xbase)**

```
$table = new Table($file, null, "Windows-1252//TRANSLIT");
```

or

```
$table = new Table($file);
```

is not working my string return :

> Ordures M‚nagŠres

I also tried to do this directly but it gives the same result:

```
echo iconv('CP1252', 'UTF-8', "Ordures M‚nagŠres");
```

> Ordures Mâ€šnagÅ res

Do you have an idea of ​​where it can come from, knowing from php-xbase uses iconv to convert characters but it has no effect I lose the accents of letters...

Thank you for your help and sorry for my bad English

Comment: i found solution, .DBF file is encoded on CP850.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the **CP850** encoding when you work with DBF files if they come from MS-DOS FoxPro applications(International MS-DOS)

In the case of a Windows DBF file, like a DBF straight up from a Visual FoxPro application, you can use **CP1252** (Windows ANSI)